# ht-access file rewrite links

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess

Having issues with my ht access file ,Im not sure if i have aproach this right but if i was to write the url as http://mywebsite/realfoldername/ it takes me there **but** I want to goto a hashed url instead. "mywebsite.com.au/#realfoldername"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Stereo /#Stereo$1?sent [QSA,NE,R]    //'sent' for JS as variable
RewriteRule ^stereo /#Stereo$1?sent [QSA,NE,R]
RewriteRule ^Television /#Television$1?sent [QSA,NE,R]
RewriteRule ^television /#television$1?sent [QSA,NE,R]
websitename example: www.hifi.com/#__    Folders    
                                    |
                                    --> Stereo/index.html
                                    |
                                    --> Television/index.html
                                    |
                                    -->Contacts/index.html
                              ______|
```

URLS http://www.hifi.com/#Stereo
   or http://www.hifi.com/#Contacts/

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("sent") > -1) {
     value =  window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') +
 1).slice(0,-5);
    window.location = value;
    loadPage();
    }else{
    loadPage();
    }
 });
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
  loadPage(); 
   console.log("fin");
});
```

Comment: why is this tagged javascript, if I may ask?

Comment: this is related to .htaccess and not JS in any way

Comment: Well yeah it is related as its looping the page continuously , I am not sure if the issue is my ht-access or JS implementation for the page loading, I have been on this for 6 hours its till looping loading